# How do I find all of a word in a text document

Tags: python, file, text

```
file = open('C:/Desktop/text.txt', encoding='utf8')
file = file.read()
result = file.findall('name') 
print (file[result+1:result+5])
```

Whenever I run this this code I get the error
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'findall'**

Comment: Why did you think `file` had a `findall()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.findall()` is a function for the regular expression module `re`, not strings.

```py
import re

file = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'

dogs = re.findall('dog', file)
```

Results:

```
['dog', 'dog', 'dog']
```

Edit:
Per your question regarding the location of the strings, you can use another re tool `.finditer()` inside list comprehension.

Example:

```py
dogs = [i.start() for i in re.finditer('dog',file)]
```

Results:

```
[41, 87, 133]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, is there a way to get the location of these words

Comment: See the additions I made to my original answer for how to get the locations of all the substring instances.

Comment: Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to count how many times a word appears in a text file, try this:

```
counter = 0
with open('path_to_file', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            if word == "word here":
                counter += 1

print(counter)
```

Replacing the `if` statement with just `print(word)` will print out every word in the file.